# Insert non-English decimal points in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can you make mysql understand non-English decimal points in integer/float fields?

```
setLocale(LC_ALL, 'da_DK.ISO-8859-1');
```

eg:

```
0,25 will be inserted as 0
0.25 will be inserted as 0.25
```

Comment: Why would `0,25` insert as zero?  SQL had a DECIMAL data type, so I'd expect the value to be stored as `0.25`

Comment: I'm assuming the parser can't handle it and is breaking on comma.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the reasons you can't do that is that the comma `,` is used for separating field-values in `INSERT` statements.

`INSERT INTO a(b,c) VALUES (3,4,5)` would be ambiguous.

Should it result into **`b=3.4 , c=5`** or **`b=3 , c=4.5`** ?

Comment: good answer. I'll never understand WHO designated the painful comma as a separator of things when there are at least [4 separators in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text)

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla those are non printable characters, aimed to be used in files. SQL is a language that is to be readable.

Comment: yes, but from the beginnings of computer ages they could have invented a printable/viewable separator char instead of using the ordinary comma. And add a key to the standard keyboard to write it. We use commas everywhere in our languaje! :)

Answer (score 3):

Numbers aren't affected by locale settings (same in SQL Server too).

So you'd have to send as "0.25"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would think would be to use a wrapper for your mysql object that will set the locale to en_US.utf8 before your query and after the query puts it back to da_DK.ISO-8859-1.

It looks like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) does the opposite of what you're looking for.

Answer (score -4):

You might want to try something like REPLACE('3,1415926', ',' , '.' )

Comment: This would only work if you have _exactly_ `3,1415926` as a string somewhere and would have to perform this for _every_ occurrence you wish to change. Hardly useful in my opinion.

Comment: This is not a solutions of asked question. please read question again carefully