# Change decimal separator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locale, decimal-point

Is it possible to change the decimal comma from "." (dot) to other character (comma) in MySQL output? I don't want to use functions like `FORMAT`, I just want to use all the queries I normaly use without any modification. I'm looking for some setting (of some variable, locale etc.). I tried to search the manual but without success.

Comment: I don't really understand this - what do you mean by "MySQL output"? Displaying a query result via the mysql command line client? Numeric values don't have a decimal separator defined by MySQL, rather they are defined by the language and framework used to output them for human use.

Comment: @MattH, I mean any client output (console, PHP, whatever). The problem in PHP is that you always get string, even if the database field is of type `double`. So there's no obvious generic solution on the PHP side, so I was looking in MySQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you can't. That's the SQL standard and MySQL complies with it (in that point at least).

The problem is not really with output (as you mention, there are various `FORMAT` functions in most DBMSs) but with `INSERT`. If you could use comma `,`  for example as decimal point (that's common in other locales) which is aslo used as values separator, Inserts would become ambiguous. See my answer in the question: [insert-non-english-decimal-points-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627239/insert-non-english-decimal-points-in-mysql/6627551#6627551)

Comment: ypercube, thanks. What is the SQL standard? The SQL query syntax, or the output format, or both? I only need the output, so that if I do `select 1/3` it outputs `0,33333`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the output format is specified in the SQL standards or that is left out and can be different for different connection methods/frameworks. But I know of no way of doing that in MySQL.

Answer (score 37):

Tip for CSV exports:
`SELECT REPLACE(CAST(prijs_incl AS CHAR), '.', ',')` will give you input that can be used as numeric fields in european excelsheets.

Comment: Useful, althou you could directly use `SELECT REPLACE(prijs_incl, '.', ',')` as string conversion is automatic, see [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: This will not work for numbers less than 1000. For example: 1.000,00 is going to be 1,000,00 . So it will not work properly