# PHP/Mysql division returns a float with "comma", How to return result with a "point"

Tags: php, mysqli

Please I have to made a small calculus using mysqli and php, and to return a float or a double value, so I've tried :

```
$notes = mysclass_sql::query("SELECT SUM(commentsNote) / COUNT(*) as c
                        FROM comments ")->fetch_object()->c;
return round( $notes , 2) ;
```

But this returns me a value like this **`1,25`** and not **`1.25`** even if I try using **str_replace** !!

I can't get out from this, please masters any help ?

Comment: Try `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US')` before the echo statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql

Comment: On a side note, why not just use `AVG()` instead of `SUM()/COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @GigaWatt will those give the same result if there are some null values for the commentsNote field? I don't know offhand, but that's probably why I'd do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$notes = mysclass_sql::query("SELECT SUM(commentsNote) / COUNT(*) as c
                    FROM comments ")->fetch_object()->c;
return(number_format($notes, 2, ".", ""));
```

fyi, this is the first hit if you google "php comma decimal".

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this if the locale is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the locale -

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "en-US");  // or "en_US", etc, depending on your server
```

Comment: On my system, `en-US` doesn't work but `en_US` does (and similarly for other locale strings).

Comment: This answer makes a lot more sense than mine if you want to print all numbers in the new format. My answer is appropriate if you want to format only some specific numbers.

Comment: *shrug, it depends on the OS.