# SQL Function sqrt

Tags: sql, function, select, sqrt

following, pre condition.

Table is called point,
columns are
id
start_long
start_lat
des_lat
des_long

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  point 
WHERE 
  SQRT((71,5x(`start_long`-`des_long`))x(71,5x(`start_long`-`des_long`))+(111,3x(`start_lat`-`des_lat`))x(111,3x(`start_lat`-`des_lat`)))<=10.0
```

I am receiving a #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) error. What is wrong?

I want to easily get the results where the square root (this is the correct function for distance between two points) is less than 10 km.

x stands for the multiplication stars

Thanks

Comment: @Fabian...what are multiplication stars?

Comment: Are the commas supposed to be decimal points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using commas for some numbers `71,5` and points in others `10.0`

I suspect you're intending to use periods `.` for your decimals, and the commas are being interpreted as separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have commas inside your `SQRT` function, causing your operand to have multiple columns.

Comment: And apparently you cannot configure mysql to accept commas as the decimal separator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql

Comment: That was the simple answer. ;-) Thanks