# PHP number_format returns 1.00

Tags: php, mysql, numerical

I have stored in MySQL the number as total(decimal 16,2) 1423.28

I get it display from PHP after making some calculations:

```
function calculate_balance($total){

 //get total paid from another function
 $total_paid = ...

 if ($total_paid == 0){
     return $total;
 }else{
     return $total-$total_paid
 }

} 

 $balance = calculate_balance($total);
 echo number_format($balance, 2); //returns 1.00
```

I have tried

```
  number_format((float)$balance, 2);
  number_format(floatval($balance), 2);
```

**UPDATE**

`var_dump($balance)`

and I got following output.

`string(8) "1,423.28" float(152) string(6) "252.00" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "549.90" string(6) "495.00" float(0) string(6) "284.76" float(265)`

It's working fine without `number_format()` for value under 1,000.
E.g.: if balance equal 252.00

```
 echo $balance;
```

output

252.00

Comment: Show us some actual values

Comment: What is the value of $total?

Comment: your if block seems useless

Comment: do a `var_dump($balance);` before using `number_format`. It's likely that your function simply returns `1`.

Comment: could the other function be returning a number to support that math?

Comment: I got this from var_dump: string(8) "1,423.28" float(152) string(6) "252.00" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "247.50" string(6) "549.90" string(6) "495.00" float(0) string(6) "284.76" float(265)

Comment: Please add it to your question, to make it readable

Comment: You are passing non-well formatted integers/floats, they are just strings, which trying to evaluate to floats are removing everything after a non-numeric character `,`

Comment: Indeed the if is useless. Thanks Royal Bg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function returns `1,423.28`? This is not a float, as a float does never contain a comma as a thousands-separator.

PHP interprets this as 1, because it "breaks" at the comma.

Remove the comma and you are fine!

```
$balance = str_replace(',', '', $balance);
```

Comment: Agree at some point but the value 1,423.28 is returned by MySQL from decimal value 1423.28. Shouldn't do something at the DB level?

Comment: @AdrianP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql

Comment: So, you said that's standard output for MySQL even the number is stored as 1423.28? I understood there is nothing to do but replace the comma for thousands separator. Thanks. I learnt something new today!

Comment: I resolved like that number_format($balance, 2, '.', '');

Answer (score 1):

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538314/5577568) of [Lars Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580794/lars-ebert) I used the function number_format like that

```
number_format($balance, 2, '.', '');
```

and that solved my problem