# Replace dot with comma on SELECT

Tags: mysql

I would like to replace any 'dot' character in my query string, on `SELECT`ing fields from database.

I'll need to modify lots of queries, I'm willing there's a function that will work to all columns on `SELECT`. I mean something like this `SELECT DOT_TO_COMMA(*) FROM...`

Right now what I have:

`SELECT price, lastprice FROM products`

`OUTPUT: 22.10, 5.24`

`EXPECTATION: 22,10, 5,25`

Comment: use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function?

Comment: You do realize that your "expectation" as for numbers instead of 2 : 22, 10 5 and 25 ...

Comment: what version of mysql?

Comment: This doesn't directly address your issue but may be worth a look: [8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql).

Comment: @mb14 thanks, for precaution. All columns will have 200.30 format so, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(price, '.', ',') AS price
FROM products;
```

- read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

You have to wrap each column you need to replace with the function. Using `replace(*)` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

please try this...

this is working

```
SELECT REPLACE(price,'.',',') AS price, REPLACE(lastprice,'.',',') AS lastprice FROM products
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case replace doesn't work well with negative numbers.

I use `SELECT FORMAT (price,0)`.
Second parameter is de decimal numbers

checkout http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-format-function/