# SQL Sum returns a false value

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have an issue with the SUM-Function in my MySQL Workbench. When I use the function, it returns a false value.
I´d like to SUM these three numbers:

- 56,03
- 35,59
- 54,35

The result should be 145,97, but its just 145 instead. I tried these different codes:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM table;
```

This one returns the value 145.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price),2) FROM table;
```

The second one returns the value 145.00.

I was wondering whats wrong with the code, because I tried it in another DB that I have in my MySQL Workbench. Also tried it over the Terminal in both databases. In the other database the function works correctly.

Comment: what is the format for the price field? in mysql number use `.`(dot) for decimal separator and not `,`(comma) as in your example data

Comment: Are you storing the values as strings like here: http://rextester.com/YNEAG27721 ?

Comment: Yes I store them in Strings, because for some reasons I could not store the data as decimal. In the other DB it works fine with strings.

Comment: My first guess would also be what @LelioFaieta suggested. I don't have an instance of mysql available to me right now to test, but I don't believe `mysql` even supports using commas as a decimal place separator (I could be wrong on that though). My guess would be that it is interpreting your values as `varchar` then when it converts to numeric, it converts only the first numeric values until it hits the comma.

Comment: What is "the other DB"?

Comment: if the data type is set as decimal then the decimal will be after a `.` See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql) as example.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Another database where I stored decimal numbers as a String and the sum function works. Same Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do would be to change your table so that it is a decimal field.

However, if you can't do that, the following query should get what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(replace(price,',', '.')) FROM tbl;
```

You can test in on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/441e6/3)

Comment: Yes it works! Big thank you. It´s still a workaround and I still try to figure out how to store my numbers as a decimal!