# MySQL prevent decimal field from rounding

Tags: mysql, csv, decimal, rounding

I have imported a csv file into the MySQL database and the `DECIMAL(3,2)` field is rounded.

In the csv file there are numbers between `0` and `1` (for example: `0,3`).

Hence I thought the definition `DECIMAL(3,2)` should be good enough if I wanted to avoid rounding. But `0,3` is rounded to `0` and I cannot explain why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show some actual lines from your raw CSV file.  `DECIMAL(3,2)` means three total digits of precision, two of which lie to the rights of the decimal point.  This would explain why a number like `100.1` is having its decimal data truncated, but it doesn't seem to explain your observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal / floating point numbers must be in the format

```
0.3
```

MySQL does not recognize `,` as a floating point character.

I think your number `0,6` would also result in `0` because it is not rounded but truncated.

Please see also [Change decimal separator in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql)