# Using comma as decimal separator in database queries

Tags: php, pdo, locale, sybase

I've set Swedish locale to use comma as decimal separator. For example it should be `123,45` instead of `123.45`.

To test it:

```
echo 100/3;
```

It gives desirable result:

```
33,333333333333
```

However when fetching or inserting data in the database using PHP PDO, it does not seem to work.
For if I try to update a table row:

```
$sql = "UPDATE
            table_name
        SET
            column_name = 123,45 //does not work but 123.45 works.
        WHERE   
            row_id = 1
    ";  
$q = $db->prepare( $sql );
$q -> execute();
```

In the above code I get error if I try to use a comma separator eg. 123,45 but it works if I use dot.
Similarly when I select the data

```
$sql = "SELECT
            column_name
        FROM
            table_name
        WHERE   
            row_id = 1
    ";  

    $q = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $q -> execute();
    $test = $q -> fetch( PDO::FETCH_COLUMN );
    var_dump($test); //string "123.45"
```

It will return the result with dot as a decimal separator. ie. 123.45 while I would like 123,45.

What I'm doing wrong?
Edit: The column data type is numeric with scale 2.

Comment: what is the data type of the column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change decimal separator in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql)

Comment: @Miggy the data type is numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be impossible for MySQL to handle because the comma is also the separator character in a list. Take for example the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES(123,45,67)
```

What does this mean? Are the values `123` and `45.67`? Or `123.45` and `67`? Could be either one. It would be totally ambiguous.

I would suggest doing all your business logic in PHP using `en_US` and changing the locale to Swedish only for output.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So I should convert 123,45 to 123.45 before inserting into database and then convert back 123.45 from database to 123,45 to display it?

Comment: You *could* do it that way, but it would be rather error-prone, like if you forget to do one of the conversions. Instead just switch once before you start outputting the page content. Of course, if your code mixes logic with output this will be nearly impossible without refactoring.

Comment: What I mean is, use `en_US` (or similar) by default and switch to whatever other locale you want only for outputting content to the page. All calculations, manipulations and database queries should be done using a locale like `en_US`.

Comment: That's right but the user input will be in local format ie. 123,45, so I guess in that case it is necessary to convert it to `en_US` before insert in database or doing any calculation.

Comment: All numbers in the database will be in the `en_US` decimal format, so there would be no need to convert that until it is outputted to the page. The only thing that you would first have to convert into `en_US` would be direct user input (i.e. `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_REQUEST`).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the comma is mistakenly read by the SQL as the comma separator in the query statement.

So I think you could do something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE
        table_name
    SET
        column_name = '123,45'
    WHERE   
        row_id = 1
";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the column data type is numeric, so it won't work in that case.

Comment: sorry about that. You could try to change the data type to make it work because comma will not be stored using the current data type

Comment: You also can't have backticks around strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP `number_format()` function.

This function accepts either one, two, or four parameters (not three):

If only one parameter is given, `number` will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

If two parameters are given, `number` will be formatted with `decimals` decimals with a dot (".") in front, and a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

If all four parameters are given, `number` will be formatted with `decimals` decimals, `dec_point` instead of a dot (".") before the decimals and `thousands_sep` instead of a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

> Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: This would work if the **only** thing needed for the other locales are the number formats, however there are many other things that can be changed when setting the locale. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php